# What License can I use in my project if I use CC-BY/CC-0 Music?

Tags: license-compatibility, cc-by, cc0

I did a google search and read through some license information, blog etc. here and there but I'm just not sure whether I can use CC-BY/CC-0 Music in my OpenSource Project no matter what license I use for that.

Should I use a software license that is compatible with the music I use or look for music that is compatible with whatever software license I am going to use (in case they are not compatible)?

EDIT: To answer the question about changing the music: It doesn't have to be changed, if the license doesn't allow it that'd be ok.

Comment: The CC BY license is compatible with almost everything. The CC 0 license is compatible with everything.

Comment: You can use CC-0 for a software project if you want but it is not advised to use CC-BY or any other creative commons license for a software project however: https://creativecommons.org/faq/#can-i-apply-a-creative-commons-license-to-software

Comment: Are you changing the music file?

Comment: @MichaelHogan Not necessarily, but aren't there CC licenses that allow changes to the content?

Comment: @Minzkraut Yes, but file modification can affect the answer and is useful info others may need to answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing more details about the software you want to build I would argue, that the music is only data used by your program. As such neither your program is a derivative work of the music, nor the other way around. This would mean, that you can freely chose the Free Software license you prefer for your project.

Answer (score 2):

They are compatible with almost everything.

When using CC-0 you have the right to do everything and when using CC-By you just need to give credits to the creator and point out changes. For example in the Readme.md

Comment: CC-BY also requires you to note changes.

Comment: CC0 in no way gives you the right to do anything. Default copyright laws still apply: in some places, moral rights can't be revoked.

Comment: @Zizouz212 CC0 grants a very permissive copyright license as a backup.

Comment: @EMBLEM Which still can't override laws.